# pg_restore without -d switch: what does it do?

Tags: postgresql

#### versions:  postgresql 9.6, macos 10.14

As the `postgres` user, I ran a pg_restore command:

`pg_restore -C backup.curated.20190901.0.bup`

i.e. create the database as per what's in the dump file.

This seems to work fine, it flashed a bunch of sql commands on the screen.

But... no database created.

In order to actually get it created I had to change the command to add a `-d` to specify a database.

`pg_restore -d postgres -C backup.curated.20190901.0.bup`

Same behavior, except the database is restored this time.

From the [pg_restore doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgrestore.html)

> -C
>   --create

```
Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.

When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.
```

Basically, I am curious why the absence of the `-d` switch isn't complained about, if it's necessary for db restoration to happen.

What does the `pg_restore` do here?  A dry-run preview?

In case it's relevant, the dump command I used was:

`sudo -u postgres $pgbin/pg_dump -o -Fc $dbname > $dirbackup/$dbname.bup;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, I am curious why the absence of the -d switch isn't
>   complained about, if it's necessary for db restoration to happen.
>
> What does the pg_restore do here? A dry-run preview?

It outputs a script without presuming what you want to do with it. Previewing, certainly, but also piping into `psql`, or to `ssh` to play it on a remote instance that you cannot reach directly, or just saving to a file to edit it or transfer it somewhere else.

In the newest version of PostgreSQL (12.0 released Oct 3, 2019) it has been estimated that too many people were surprised as you are by `pg_restore` going to the standard output **by default**, so starting from that release we now need to specify a `-f -` argument to get that behavior. The first invocation you mentioned now fails with:

```
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified
```

Answer (score 1):

The flags needed with [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgrestore.html)  depend on  both:

- the current state of the database/server before you start a restore
- on the flags used to create the backup of a single database with [`gd_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html)
- on the flags used to create a complete server backup with [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pg-dumpall.html)

and that last one is the reason `pg_restore -C` does not require have a mandatory (single) `-d <database name>` dependency,  the backup file can contain the backups more than one database and when that is the case then the names of those databases will included in the backup file.